# Put the current value of a style attribute to a variable

Tags: jquery

I have the following dynamic code. I want to put the position values "left" and "top" into variables. These values change as I drag this around the screen. What I would like to do is to store the last values so that when it gets destroyed, I can reuse the values to position it at the same place the next time.

```
<div onmouseover="setTimer();" class="soft_add_wrapper ui-draggable" style="left: 630.5px; top: 182px;">
```

I have the selector I think but then I am a little fussy

```
var xyz = $(".soft_add_wrapper ui-draggable").attr xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the values with [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) like this:

```
var left = $(".soft_add_wrapper.ui-draggable").css('left');
var top = $(".soft_add_wrapper.ui-draggable").css('top');
```

If it's relative to the entire document and you want the overall position, you might consider using [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), or if you want relative to the parent, [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/).

Note that the selector is `.soft_add_wrapper.ui-draggable` since you want to check both class selectors on the same element, there's no space.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Nick as always. You must live here, LOL It looks right to me. Give me a few to check it in my specific applications

Comment: @user357034: Yup, or just `.css({left: left, right: right})` works as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You could just do

```
var offset = $(".soft_add_wrapper.ui-draggable").offset();
```

which will then be accessed like:

```
alert(offset.left);
alert(offset.top);
```

Comment: No problem. :) I think your answer was the best. But then again... The OP might have his reasons for dabbling with CSS values.